# Publish a WCFService doesn't work; Debugging-mode works

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis

I want to start an default webservice-project, where I can send data over a service. When I go to debug the API through VS then everything works fine, but not when I try to use it over IIS.

I created an WcfServiceLibrary-Project in Visual Studio 2017. I then right-clicked on the project (in the solution explorer) and then published it to a folder A.

I also didn't do anything special at IIS (all the things are still on localhost.): I activated the default windows-feature "IIS". (The default web site got also stopped). Then I added there a site with an random name and the path to the folder A. The service got started.

My access trial was to find anything through Visual Studios "connected services".

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Describe what exactly is the problem. If you found it hard to, use screen shots.

Comment: Over IIS do you means IIS get crashed? Could you check IIS log and find what the status code? Besides, could you post the error message in  application or system event log? If we need to know what happened in IIS , please provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please use the WCF service application project template,
[image]
or the Appconfig file would not be kicked in. library project needs the additional configuration in the hosting environment, and the Appconfig file could not recognized. We have to move the configuration code into the configuration file recognized by your hosting environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/deploying-a-wcf-library-project
Secondly, for hosting the WCF service in IIS, we should enable the below windows feature.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: There followed another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076452/iis-10-how-can-i-solve-403-in-the-production-environment