# IIS 10: How can I solve 403 in the production environment?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, iis

EDIT: SOLUTION in the comment!

I have to offer a SOAP service. He indicates a HTTP-403 error. I need access to the http://10.234.35.19:80/?wsdl and the API SPAPort.

Therefore, I assume that either my configuration is wrong or the file permissions on the folder. Which user does one have to give read access to a server? Maybe the  should be replaced with service?

The code below shows the production environment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<!--
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
                      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                      initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics> -->

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SPASoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.234.35.19:80/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="SPASoapBinding" contract="SPAPortType"
          name="SPAPort" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

This trial worked but I didn't reached access from another computer (only from local). Please note that access is now only possible via the svc file.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

EDIT:
The locally working Web.config file has the following error on an client (the web server shows nothing):

```
   bei System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   bei System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   bei System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   bei System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   bei KOS_Tester.ServiceReference1.KOSPortTypeClient..ctor()
   bei KOS_Tester.Form1.serverKOSAusführen(String strPfadRequest)Es wurde kein standardmäßiges Endpunktelement gefunden, das auf den Vertrag "ServiceReference1.KOSPortType" im ServiceModel-Clientkonfigurationsabschnitt verweist. Dies kann folgende Ursachen haben: Für die Anwendung wurde keine Konfigurationsdatei gefunden, oder im Clientelement wurde kein Endpunktelement gefunden, das diesem Vertrag entsprach.
```

Translated:

No default endpoint element was found that points to the ServiceReference1.KOSPortType contract in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This document has no set-file element, no contract file found.

The other Web.config-file throws no specific 403-error.

I uploaded my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/81em9slycdb4wnk/WcfService6.zip?dl=0&m=

Comment: Do you enable the https for your wcf application ? According to your description, I suggest you could try to check the IIS logs to tell us which kinds of 403 error you have faced now. Since the 403 has multiple sub status. For example: 403.4 - SSL required.

Comment: The error was in the client. It was an standard wcf-project and had no .config-File.