# Error to publish a site with WCF Soap in a IIS Server

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, soap

I have a site published in a IIS Server, but now i am adding a Connected Service using a WCF Soap  to access another server.
Basically, my site needs consult a information from another server, and to this he needs to WCF.
When i publish my site in my homolog server, he death, and returne HTTP ERROR 500. However, in a localhost is normal.
I'm using a netcore 2.2

Comment: 1)  Learn from IIS log files, what's the substatus code for those 500, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 2) Learn to handle unhandled exceptions.

Comment: 500 also have something to do with a crash. So first of all. please review your substatus code. Because 500 and 500.19 is totally different error. It the error is pure 500.0.Then please post your event viewer system and application event that generated when you access the website. If the error is 500.19, then please ensure .net core web hosting bundle has been installed https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Comment: try to enable the Window feature for supporting WCF in IIS.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026230/publish-a-wcfservice-doesnt-work-debugging-mode-works/58055154#58055154